# Multiple wilcox.tests across columns using variables in first column (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, multiple-columns, pairwise.wilcox.test

I have this data.frame

```
 df <- data.frame(
      variable=c(2.4860651, -0.68863024, 2.63530974, -2.95754943, 1.67945091, 2.63530974,
           4.79002539, 2.32575938, 3.57236441, -0.364825998, -2.00646016, -3.12380516, 
           0.69307013, -5.65846824, 0.45632519, 2.08978142),
      A=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
      B=c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
      C=c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
      D=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
      E=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
      F=c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1))
```

I would like to perform `wilcox.test` for each column with groups defined by 0 and 1 in the columns and using the variables in the column `df$variable`. Then add the p.values in a new row and adjusted p.values in another row.

I have tried this:

```
 library(dplyr)
 result <- df %>% summarise(across(!variable, ~wilcox.test(.x ~ variable)$p.value), exact=NULL) %>%
         bind_rows(., p.adjust(., method = 'BH')) %>%
         bind_rows(df, .) %>%
         mutate(variable=replace(variable, is.na(variable), c('p.values', 'p.adjust')))
```

But this causes errors.

This is the result I would like to get:

```
 result <- data.frame(
      variable=c(2.4860651, -0.68863024, 2.63530974, -2.95754943, 1.67945091, 2.63530974,
           4.79002539, 2.32575938, 3.57236441, -0.364825998, -2.00646016, -3.12380516, 
           0.69307013, -5.65846824, 0.45632519, 2.08978142, 'p.value', 'p.adjust'),
      A=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
      B=c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.560444274, 1),
      C=c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0.143117298, 0.764253489),
      D=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.820753088, 1),
      E=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.95482869, 1),
      F=c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0.254751163, 0.764253489))
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something along the lines of the following -

```
library(dplyr)

tmp <- df %>% summarise(across(!variable, 
          ~wilcox.test(variable[.x == 0], variable[.x == 1])$p.value)) 

adj_value <- p.adjust(unlist(tmp), method = "BH")

result <- bind_rows(df %>% mutate(variable = as.character(variable)), 
          rbind(tmp, adj_value) %>%
                  mutate(variable = c('p.values', 'p.adjust'))
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ronak. I really like your solution. I just wondered if the result is correct, because for column A zeroes: ```x <- c(2.4860651, -0.68863024, 2.63530974, -2.95754943, 2.63530974, 4.79002539, 2.32575938, 3.57236441, -0.364825998, -2.00646016, -3.12380516, -5.65846824, 0.45632519, 2.08978142)``` and ones: ```y <- c(1.67945091, 0.69307013)``` then ```wilcox.test(x,y)$p.value``` = 1, instead of 0.2789041? Thank you.

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez I think I misunderstood your question earlier. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Oh this is excellent! Thank you. Just one more question. All ```p.adjust``` are the same as ```p.values```. Do you know how to correct this last issue please?

Comment: It was getting too complex to do it in single pipe so I have broken it down into smaller steps. Hope the update is what you were looking for @SylviaRodriguez

Comment: Thank you Ronak! See also my added answer based on your excellent answers. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Ronak. I modified your former answer and I found that this also works and results in the same as you found:

```
 result <- df %>% 
       summarise(across(!variable, 
           ~wilcox.test(variable[.x == 0], variable[.x == 1])$p.value), exact=NULL) %>%
       bind_rows(., p.adjust(., method = 'BH')) %>%
       bind_rows(df, .) %>% 
       mutate(variable=replace(variable, is.na(variable), c('p.values', 'p.adjust')))
```

Thank you! :)